# JPA EclipseLink Second Level Cache

Tags: jpa, caching, eclipselink

I wanted to enable caching on my application based on JPA and EclipseLink.

I wanted to cache only meta data entities because they never change so I added some configuration but I didn't manage to have the cache working properly.

In my presistence xml I have :

```
<prop key="javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode">ENABLE_SELECTIVE</prop>
<prop key="eclipselink.cache.shared.default">true</prop>
<prop key="javax.persistence.storeMode">"USE</prop>
<prop key="javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode">"USE</prop>
```

And now imagine I have Entity A referencing Entity B in a @ManyToOne association. Adding @Cacheable or @Cache doesn't make EclipseLink put B in the cache. I know that because when check sql queries, I see that it keeps on retrieving entity B all the time. Now if I add @Cacheable on A, both entities A and B are cached.

So the question is: how to instruct EclipseLink to store only B in the cache.

I remember doing something similar with hibernate.

Here entity manager configuration :

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="my.domain"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="eclipselink.weaving">false</prop>
            <prop key="eclipselink.logging.file">sql.log</prop>
            <prop key="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode">both</prop>
            <prop key="eclipselink.logging.level">INFO</prop>
            <prop key="eclipselink.logging.parameters">true</prop>
            <prop key="eclipselink.logging.level.sql">ALL</prop>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">NONE</prop>
            <prop key="eclipselink.ddl-generation">none</prop>
                
            <!-- Cache -->
            <prop key="javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode">ENABLE_SELECTIVE</prop>
            <prop key="eclipselink.cache.shared.default">true</prop>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.storeMode">"USE</prop>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode">"USE</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceProvider">
        <bean class="org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Here simplified mapping :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="REPORT")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class Report {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "S_RPID", initialValue = 1000, sequenceName = "S_RPID", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "S_RPID")
    protected Long id;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="RPTY_KY", nullable = false)
    private ReportType type;
    
}

@Entity
@Table(name="REPORT_TYPE")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Cacheable
@Cache(
        type = CacheType.SOFT,
        size = 1000,
        expiry = 100000000,
        coordinationType = CacheCoordinationType.INVALIDATE_CHANGED_OBJECTS
        )
public class ReportType {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "S_RTID", initialValue = 1000, sequenceName = "S_RTID", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "S_RTID")
    @Min(value = 1)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name="NAME", nullable = false, length = 50)
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Not quite sure what you are seeing or looking for. If A isn't in the cache, every time you go and read the OneToMany (eager or lazy) it has to query the database to see which Bs are needed. Bs can still be cached - the db will be checked, but the data not really used other than to determine which Bs are needed. They get pulled from the cache if they are already there, otherwise they are built from the returned data and placed in the cache. That is what I'd expect - you can confirm the Bs are cached by executing findbyId for a specific B on different Ems

Comment: A with ID a1 has a B with ID b2. Get by ID (a1) runs always 2 queries :

`SELECT FROM TABLE_A WHERE ID = a1`
`SELECT FROM TABLE_B WHERE ID = b2`

Comment: We cannot see what options you used on EntityB. Show the entity and the annotations (@Cacheable(true), right) and code used for your testing. You haven't mentioned the container used - some containers transaction handling might interfere with how and when the shared cache can be populated - reading from a transaction prevents that data from being pushed into the shared cache immediately or other processes would see uncommitted changes. Enable eclipseLink logging and it should tell you what it is doing, when and why.

Comment: Yes I have cache enabled on Entity B :

`@Cacheable`
I also tried 
`@Cache(type = CacheType.SOFT, size = 1000, expiry = 1000000, coordinationType = CacheCoordinationType.INVALIDATE_CHANGED_OBJECTS)`

I use spring framework and spring data.

Comment: Here the entityManager configuration:

Comment: See updated question for EntityManager configuration.

In the logs I see EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.8.v20201217-ecdf3c32c4 and then the 2 queries I mentioned before

Comment: Did you do simple find by ids for a particular B? Maybe show the code, the annotations and what is logged. If logging is on all, you should see a lot more than the version and two queries. And as mentioned, if A is not cached, it will need to query for Bs always to make sure it has them all - is that what you are seeing?

Comment: No I didn't do find by ID for B. I really don't want to cache A, just B. I don't understand why it's not possible. He can do the query to fetch the A(s), and see first in the cache if corresponding B is there, otherwise, run a query to fetch B

Comment: It IS possible, and it is likely B IS being cached. Try a findbyid on B to prove if there is or isn't a cache - this has nothing to do with As. Your 'second' query is, as I tried to explain, likely because A has a 1:M to B. Caches cache on the primary key- A doesn't have references to B's id, so when building As, JPA providers have to go to the database to figure out which Bs reference the fetched A. Technically it could look in the cache at all Bs and find which reference the A you fetched, but I won't go into why that isn't done.

Comment: Indeed find by Id on B doesn't run a query which is good but not solving my "issue". I have a many to one relation from A to B. I don't understand why you say "A doesn't have references to B's id" the foreign key is in table A so after running the query on A he gets the ID and so can check if corresponding object is in the cache

Comment: Show the entity. We cannot guess at your mapping or why this does what you say it does without more information - especially since you say it is OneToMany relationship from A to B. If A references and has a foreign key to B it will operate using the cache if B is cached - the same behavior you see with an explicit findbyid query. You said you had a 1:M though which cannot work with A having a foriegn key that references B's ID value - there is either a join table or a foreign key IN B that points at A's ID. The only way reasonable way to resolve that is to query the database.

Comment: Hi, I added the mappings

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251376/discussion-between-chris-and-kchetoua).

Comment: You might fix your question to detail that it is a ManyToOne from A to B, and show code used to fetch As and Bs, and why you think a cache isn't being used - ie show the queries and the test case. Also note that Cache and Cacheable annotations can't both be used - only one is picked up. Same with persistence properties. Turn on EclipseLink logging to finest to see what properties/annotations are actually getting picked up